# Need help fetching data JSON to scope AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, getjson, codeigniter-3

i am newbie at AngularJS and in now trying to learn it. This time i am learning how to create one page app using codeigniter and angular with RESTful lib.

I have JSON like this :

```
[{"id":"25","title":"abc","description":"sss"},{"id":"26","title":"sd","description":"sdsd"}]
```

i just cannot fetch it to `$scope` with `ng-repeat` working no matter what i do. This is my function :

```
$http.get('Api/items').then(function(response)
        {       
            $scope.items = response;
            console.log(response);
        });
```

and this is my table view :

```
<table class="table table-bordered pagin-table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>No</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th width="220px">Action</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in items">
        <td>{{ $index + 1 }}</td>
        <td>{{ x.title }}</td>
        <td>{{ x.description }}</td>
        <td>
            <button data-toggle="modal" ng-click="edit(x.id)" data-target="#edit-data" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
            <button ng-click="remove(x,$index)" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

This is what happen when those all executed :
[image]

no array fetched by $scope at all. weird thing is the `<tr>` is repeated 5 time without any value. but when i call array[0] the $scope can fetch it :

```
<table class="table table-bordered pagin-table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>No</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th width="220px">Action</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in items">
        <td>{{ $index + 1 }}</td>
        <td>{{ x[0].title }}</td>
        <td>{{ x[0].description }}</td>
        <td>
            <button data-toggle="modal" ng-click="edit(x.id)" data-target="#edit-data" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
            <button ng-click="remove(x,$index)" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

[image]

Where did i go wrong?? can someone help me??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because the promise returning raw HTTP response from the server rather than parsed result data. You should try this instead :

```
$http.get('Api/items').then(function(response)
        {       
            $scope.items = response.data;
            console.log(response);
        });
```

Comment: ah, yeah, thanks man, there are some improvement, the <tr> is repeated 2 time like what json give. but still no value though?? can you help me check again? ss : http://imgur.com/a/I7Me2

Comment: sorry, forgot to erase array number, my mistake

Comment: It should have value if count is true. Is it show blank row instead?

Comment: Please modify x[0].title -> x.title only.

Answer (score 2):

@digit already pointed the issue in you $hhtp call. Now For this JSON:

```
 [{"id":"25","title":"abc","description":"sss"},{"id":"26","title":"sd","description":"sdsd"}]
```

.
    No need to give index number inside ng-repeat. `//{{ x[0].title }}`

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in items">
        <td>{{ $index + 1 }}</td>
        <td>{{ x.title }}</td>
        <td>{{ x.description }}</td>
        <td>
            <button data-toggle="modal" ng-click="edit(x.id)" data-target="#edit-data" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
            <button ng-click="remove(x,$index)" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: thanks for the full explanation. but because @didit give the answer first i will accept his answer. i can only upvote your anwser. if only we can accept multiple answer.